If students use academic licenses to perform work for commercial firms, but as part of class projects, is that a license violation?
Assume that a university has a program that solicits computing projects from industry partners. These projects are directly in service of the commercial entities' businesses. The organizations may or may not donate funds to the university as part of the arrangement but no payment to the university is explicitly required. Some of the organizations are large and may involve thousands of employees, so would easily exceed any "small business" licensing allowances.
The university and their faculty then assign these projects to students in computing programs as part of an independent study or as part of a course focusing on "real-world" experience. Students may work on a variety of projects for short periods of time each, usually a semester or two.
Simple examples of projects:

Refactor a database to improve performance
Update a website to use a newer framework version
Containerize an existing service application stack using Docker
Develop a prototype of an application for a specific business need
Evaluate and update DevOps pipelines and processes
"Port" an Android application to iOS or vice versa
Update a mobile application to target a newer OS.
Optimize the processing algorithms in a web or desktop application to improve performance

In all cases, the products of the students' work are delivered to the respective organizations, who then either does or does not use the work done, or may adapt, fix or improve the work submitted by students. Some organizations may simply offer a real scenario for students to practice on but have no intent to actually use their work; other organizations will actually implement the work provided by students into production (after review by the org's internal software processes). We can't necessarily know ahead of time which of these will happen.
Students understand that their contributions may become intellectual property of the business, however in all cases students are explicitly permitted to retain the work in their portfolios. The only restriction may be if a student handles private or confidential data, in which case any retained artifacts must be scrubbed of such data.
Students have naturally been using software offered for free under academic licenses throughout their schooling. There are many examples of software that are licensed free for academic use but incur cost when used "for commercial purposes". Examples include but aren't limited to:

Docker (requires commercial license for commercial use)
Visual Studio Community (only licensed for very small orgs, academia or open source projects)
JetBrains tools (many are free for academic use only)
VMware Workstation (free only for personal or academic use)
SPSS, Microsoft Office, etc. (offered for free or heavily discounted under academic licensing programs at the university)

Additionally, the university itself may provide its own resources in service of students' work on the projects. As an example, the university may provide an academic-licensed Windows virtual machine or database server, which the student may use to test their software in a semi-production environment. This is to prevent needing to give students direct access to corporate networks and test environments for very short term projects. The university works with IT staff from the organizations to produce a suitable replica of the testing or production environment for students to test and practice in. The university will use its academic licenses to implement any such software.
In this scenario, is a license violation being committed if students use their academic software to perform these projects?
Concerns are:

Many programs are licensed for unlimited use by academia, but require payment in a commercial setting for any reason, even a single user. This is a unique case because the work is both academic (it's not paid nor is it an internship, it's part of a course) and commercial (it may directly benefit an organization's commercial interests).
There could be a lot of issues with organizations issuing corporate licenses to students - for example, IT policy or the software itself might require licensed software to contact a license server within the corporate VPN, which the company may have good reason not to open to a temporary student for a few months.
Some corporate licenses cannot be purchased "individually" - i.e. some programs may say "free for orgs up to 50 people, beyond that you have to license, hence our lowest price is for 51 licenses".
Some companies may have a "site license" which permits use for all computers at a specific location - students would not be considered to be "at that location" since they still do their work in classrooms, on campus or at their own residences. (Again, I've seen some software that counts corporate VPN as "location", but students would not be given access to the corporate VPN.)
Ensuring license compliance among a random set of university students could be a challenge. Such students may not be able to be included in a company audit.
Naturally, assuming a commercial license can even be purchased by an individual student, that is a huge cost burden for students to bear for a 3-6 month project for which they aren't even receiving any compensation other than a grade.

Note that I'm not referring to software unique to an organization, I'm thinking about software that is commonly used by students, and would be free for them as long as their use remains academic, but would require licensing for "commercial" use. Docker is the prominent example that comes to mind.

As you have identified, much will depend on exactly what the terms of the academic software licence are — whether the licence includes a definition of "academic use", whether the scope of the licence is limited by the purpose of the use or the purposes to which the generated work products are put, whether there are any geographical restrictions, etc.
This is probably an open question at law, and I would be surprised if there is any case law specifically on this issue. You should of course do a check in the relevant jurisdiction (you don't seem to have specified any particular jurisdiction), but broadly speaking (subject to the factors above and factual confirmation), I think it could be possible for the student to take the position that their use of the software is actually purely academic and not commercial at all, and therefore within the scope of the licence.

The purpose of having the students work on real-world problems is to help the students pick up practical skills and better understand how software development occurs in the real world. In other words, the purpose is educational in nature, and the projects mentioned are being conducted within the framework of a university course.
At no time is there any formal contractual arrangement between the students and the industry partner. As you have stated above, the students are not interns or contractors, and neither the students nor the university are paid for this work.

The fact that some industry partners do not intend to use the students' work or do not actually use the students' work will probably also go some way in supporting the argument that the programme is educational and academic and not commercial.
The argument above could be strengthened further by making some small tweaks to the structure of the programme, for example:

By requiring the industry partners to provide the student with feedback and mentorship (thereby strengthening the educational aspect of the programme).
By making it clear to the industry partners that the students' work is provided as-is, may be defective, poor quality, etc. and will not necessarily be appropriate for the industry partners' purposes, and it is the industry partners' sole responsibility to review the students work product, and decide whether or not to use (and whether or not to revise it).

In many ways, the students' contributions are analogous to contributions to an open source project that is subsequently used by a commercial company.

I think it would have to be the case that the company doesn't intend to use the result commercially. If the company does use it, the student is acting like an unpaid intern/employee.
